# installing java JDK 7 to run javafx - osx

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, javafx

I have installed `java JDK 7` in my osx. It is installed in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` where are `1.6` java version is installed in `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`. Which is fine in my case, since I only want to use `JDK 7` inside `intelliJ` ide to run `javafx`. So I added in `intelliJ` project structure the `1.7` `SDK`, but none of my `import javafx.*` work. How can it be ? How can I check that `1.7` `SDK` is can be resolved by my `ide`

Comment: Have you specified project `JDK` to be `Java` 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify `JDK` to be `Java` 7 in the project settings.

For example:

[image: Example]